# CreateDirectory crashes program

Tags: c, crash, create-directory

So I'm trying to create a directory and I cannot figure out why its dying when I do. I've tried a hardcode test of the path so I don't think its a permission issue. When I cut apart the path I want to create, I make sure to NULL terminate the string. I've even tried to get the error with `GetLastError()` but it crashes the program so I can't. What have I done wrong?

EDIT::
If I uncomment the line in main, let it create the folder and delete it before I try to create it again in the function, the function succeeds. what...is this actually a permission issue somehow?

```
int main(void) {
   int start;

   char* test = "C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\temp\\second";
   //   CreateDirectory(test, NULL);  //this works

   fileCopy("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\temp\\second\\datanew.txt");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


int fileCopy(char* path){

char line[500];

FILE *new;
FILE *old;

char *old_path = "C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\temp\\data.txt";

//"C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\temp.txt"
old = fopen(old_path, "r");
new = fopen(path, "w");

if(old != NULL){
        if(new == NULL){

            char * last;
            last = strrchr(path, 92); //the \ character

            int size = strlen(path)-strlen(last);

            char *dir;
            dir = memcpy(dir, path, size + 1);
            dir[size] = '\0';
            CreateDirectory(dir, NULL);
            new = fopen(path, "w");
        }

}

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't allocate any memory for "dir".

```
char *dir;
dir = malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));
dir = memcpy(dir, path, size + 1);
```

Comment: ...in other words, Daniel, it´s no permission issue, but "just" undefined behaviour in your program.

Comment: ok, thanks it worked. this may outside the scope of an answer, why would doing what I described in my edit cause it to work? and why was the correct value showing up in the debugger?

Comment: Automatic variables (like dir) are alocated in the stack without any initialization (it takes any value present in the stack). It looks like calling CreateDirectory() leaves a value that match a free position in memory in the position of the stack where dir will be allocated when you call fileCopy().

Comment: As for the debugger I don't know, as @deviantfan wrote this is an undefined behaviour an as such you can expect any sort of results depending of which compiler you use, which OS, which optimization level, etc...